# Merging two nested maps in scala

Tags: scala, parsing, hashmap

I have nested maps with a `key -> Map(key1 -> Map(), key2 -> Map())` kinda representation, which basically represent the path structure of a particular HTTP request made.

`root/twiki/bin/edit/Main/Double_bounce_sender
root/twiki/bin/rdiff/TWiki/NewUserTemplate`

I have stored them in a Map of maps which would give me the hierarchy of the path. Using a parser I read the data off server logs and get the corresponding data needed and then index the data in a sorted map.

```
val mainList: RDD[List[String]] = requesturl flatMap ( r => r.toString split("\\?") map (x => parser(x.split("/").filter(x => !x.contains("=")).toList).valuesIterator.toList))

def parser(list: List[String]): Map[Int, String]= {
val m = list.zipWithIndex.map(_.swap).toMap
val sM = SortedMap(m.toSeq:_*)
sM.+(0 -> "root")
}
```

After getting the data in the structure required, I loop through the entire collection to structure the data into a path map which would look like

`root - twiki - bin - edit - Main - Double_bounce_sender
                    -rdiff - TWiki - NewUserTemplate
              - oops - etc - local - getInterface`

```
type innerMap = mutable.HashMap[String, Any]

def getData(input: RDD[List[String]]): mutable.HashMap[String, innerMap] ={
var mainMap = new mutable.HashMap[String, innerMap]
for(x <- input){
  val z: mutable.HashMap[String, innerMap] = storeData(x.toIterator, mainMap ,x(0).toString)
  mainMap = mainMap ++ z
}
mainMap
}

def storeData(list: Iterator[String], map: mutable.HashMap[String, innerMap], root: String): mutable.HashMap[String, innerMap]={
list.hasNext match {
  case true =>
    val v = list.next()
    val y = map contains (root) match {
      case true =>
        println("Adding when exists: "+v)
        val childMap = map.get(v).get match {
          case _:HashMap[String, Any] => asInstanceOf[mutable.HashMap[String, innerMap]]
          case _ => new mutable.HashMap[String, innerMap]
        }
        val x = map + (v -> storeData(list, childMap, v))
        x
      case false =>
        val x = map + (v -> storeData(list, new mutable.HashMap[String, innerMap], v))
        x
    }
    y.asInstanceOf[mutable.HashMap[String, innerMap]]
  case false =>
    new mutable.HashMap[String, innerMap]
    }
}
```

The get data method calls each input list and sends it to the storeData method which builds the map.

I'm stuck at two places.

- The MainMap(HashMap[String, innerMap]) sent recursively to storeData goes as a new empty map every time.
- The second issue is that I'm trying to figure out a way of merging 2 nested Maps that do not have a defined length. Such as merging the maps below.

`Map(root -> Map(twiki -> Map(bin -> Map(edit -> Map(Main -> Map(Double -> Map())))))))
Map(root -> Map(twiki -> Map(bin -> Map(rdiff -> Map(TWiki -> Map(NewUser -> Map())))))))`

Looking for suggestions on how I could implement this solution and get a final map that contains all the possible paths present in the server log files in one map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
scala>   type Node = Map[String, Any];
defined type alias Node

scala>   def merge( me : Node, you : Node ) : Node = {
     |     val keySet = me.keySet ++ you.keySet;
     |     def nodeForKey( parent : Node, key : String ) : Node = parent.getOrElse( key, Map.empty ).asInstanceOf[Node]
     |     keySet.map( key => (key -> merge( nodeForKey( me, key ), nodeForKey( you, key ) ) ) ).toMap
     |   }
merge: (me: Node, you: Node)Node

scala> val path1 = Map( "root" -> Map("bin" -> Map("sh" -> Map.empty) ) )
path1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Map[Nothing,Nothing]]]] = Map(root -> Map(bin -> Map(sh -> Map())))

scala> val path2 = Map( "root" -> Map( "bin" -> Map("csh" -> Map.empty), "usr" -> Map.empty ) )
path2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Map[_ <: String, scala.collection.immutable.Map[Nothing,Nothing]]]] = Map(root -> Map(bin -> Map(csh -> Map()), usr -> Map()))

scala> merge( path1, path2 )
res8: Node = Map(root -> Map(bin -> Map(sh -> Map(), csh -> Map()), usr -> Map()))
```

Comment: This solution might work, but the required output would have to look a little different. According to your solution above the out put would be 
`Map(root -> Map(bin -> Map(sh -> Map(), csh -> Map()), usr -> Map()))`, 
but it should be
 `Map(root -> Map(bin -> Map(sh -> Map(), csh -> Map(usr -> Map()))))`

Answer (score 2):

to merge these two maps you can use scalaz and `|+|` method

```
@ Map("root" ->
    Map("twiki" ->
      Map("bin" ->
        Map("rdiff" ->
          Map("TWiki" ->
            Map("NewUser" ->
              Map.empty[String, String]))))))
res2: Map[String, Map[String, Map[String, Map[String, Map[String, Map[String, Map[String, String]]]]]]] =
  Map("root" ->
    Map("twiki" ->
      Map("bin" ->
        Map("rdiff" ->
          Map("TWiki" ->
            Map("NewUser" -> Map()))))))

@ Map("root" ->
    Map("twiki" ->
      Map("bin" ->
        Map("edit" ->
          Map("Main" ->
            Map("Double" ->  Map.empty[String, String]))))))
res3: Map[String, Map[String, Map[String, Map[String, Map[String, Map[String, Map[String, String]]]]]]] =
  Map("root" ->
    Map("twiki" ->
      Map("bin" ->
        Map("edit" ->
          Map("Main" ->
            Map("Double" -> Map()))))))

res2 |+| res3
res4: Map[String, Map[String, Map[String, Map[String, Map[String, Map[String, Map[String, String]]]]]]] =
  Map("root" ->
    Map("twiki" ->
      Map("bin" ->
        Map(
          "edit" ->
            Map("Main" ->
              Map("Double" -> Map())),
          "rdiff" ->
            Map("TWiki" ->
              Map("NewUser" -> Map()))))))
```

Comment: I will not be able to be able to use the `|+| method` when the you use a `collection.mutable.HashMap` or even a `collection.immutable.Map[String, Any]`

Comment: Maps need to be of the same type, your maps from example are so I asumed that. I don't have a simple solution for any maps. Btw, try to read what you are posting as this is clearly not in English.

Comment: My Maps are of the same type, but scalaz doesn't allow you to implement the |+| method on a mutable map `collection.mutable.HashMap`.
This is the error I get 
`error: value |+| is not a member of scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any]`.
I would either have to change the collection i'm using to a Map type or write some logic to do exactly what the |+| method does but to a mutable map.

Comment: yes it is not a member of Map[String, Any] because it doesn't know how to merge `Any` with `Any`. If any of nested maps has elements of more than one type I don't know how to merge it easly.